# Customizing CakePHP Plugins

Tags: cakephp, plugins, customization

So normally, if you are developing a web application you will have to create your own .css files. In my case, I used bootstrap to design my application and created my own .css files to suit my needs.

Recently, I just found this Report Manager plugin for CakePHP. I put my plugin in the plugin folder and loaded it on my bootstrap.php file. Everything went smoothly and I can create reports.

Now, this is my first time handling plugins. Since this Report Manager plugin is using the default CakePHP design, how can I apply the bootstrap and my own design to this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation!](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application)

> You can override any plugin views from inside your app using special
>   paths. If you have a plugin called ‘ContactManager’ you can override
>   the template files of the plugin with application specific view logic
>   by creating files using the following template
>   src/Template/Plugin/[Plugin]/[Controller]/[view].ctp. For the Contacts
>   controller you could make the following file:

Comment: I don't see the src/Template anywhere in the plugin folder. Should I create it?

Comment: **Always** name your CakePHP version. Just look it up in the 2.0 documentation if you're using 2.0. It's /View/Plugin/ there. Simple things like that can be easy resolved by taking  a quick look at the documentation.